# Angular version of FitText

Tags: javascript, html, angular.js

This project has [evolved a lot](https://github.com/patrickmarabeas/ng-FitText.js/blob/49038a2d0857194edfd83ad6fd62f62185f43a26/angularjs-fittext.js) since I started learning Angular. I'm pretty happy with it now, and I'm wondering if there's anything I can improve upon, or have forgotten at this point...

**HTML**

```
<h1 data-fittext>FitText</h1>

<h1 data-fittext=".315" data-fittext-min="12" data-fittext-max="50">ng-FitText</h1>
```

**Inclusion & Customization**

```
var myApp = angular.module( 'myApp', [ 'ngFitText' ] );

myApp.config( function( fitTextConfigProvider ) {
    fitTextConfigProvider.config = {
        debounce: true, //default is false
        delay: 1000 //default is 250
    };

    // OR

    fitTextConfigProvider.config.debounce = true;
    fitTextConfigProvider.config.delay = 1000;
});
```

**The Module**

```
'use strict';

angular.module( 'ngFitText', [] )
    .value( 'config', {
        'debounce': false,
        'delay': 250
    })

    .directive( 'fittext', [ 'config', 'fitTextConfig', function( config, fitTextConfig ) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            transclude: true,
            replace: true,
            template: function( element, attrs ) {
                var tag = element[0].nodeName;
                return "<"+tag+" data-ng-transclude data-ng-style='{fontSize:fontSize}'></"+tag+">";
            },
            link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {
                angular.extend(config, fitTextConfig.config);

                scope.compressor = attrs.fittext || 1;
                scope.minFontSize = attrs.fittextMin || Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
                scope.maxFontSize = attrs.fittextMax || Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
                scope.elementWidth = element[0].offsetWidth;

                ( scope.resizer = function() {
                    scope.elementWidth = element[0].offsetWidth;
                    scope.fontSize = Math.max(
                        Math.min(
                            scope.elementWidth / ( scope.compressor * 10 ),
                            parseFloat( scope.maxFontSize )
                        ),
                        parseFloat( scope.minFontSize )
                    ) + 'px';

                    if( !scope.$$phase ) scope.$digest();
                })();

                config.debounce == true
                    ? angular.element( window ).bind( 'resize', debounce( scope.resizer, config.delay ))
                    : angular.element( window ).bind( 'resize', scope.resizer);

                function debounce(a,b,c){var d;return function(){var e=this,f=arguments;clearTimeout(d),d=setTimeout(function(){d=null,c||a.apply(e,f)},b),c&&!d&&a.apply(e,f)}}
            }
        }
    }])

    .provider( 'fitTextConfig', function() {
        var self = this;
        this.config = {};
        this.$get = function() {
            var extend = {};
            extend.config = self.config;
            return extend;
        };
        return this;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

- As personal opinion, I wouldn't use `config` as name for `.value`, it sounds too generic and can be confused with `.config` method of the `module` API.
- Putting comments like `//default is false` looks confusing - why are these not default? Also it is easy to change the defaults and forget to adjust comments. Uncle Bob recommends to minimize comments and use expressive code with descriptive names instead.
- `function debounce(a,b,c)` is great for minimizers but cryptic for code readers
- In my view, using `.provider` is possibly an overkill as there is not much configuration logic here.
- The last two comments [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/47882/29119) also apply. Instead the config JSON can be kept inside `.value` and decoupled from the provider.

Comment: Thanks for your points. The debounce function is taken from Underscore and stated as such in the module comments. Overkill doesn't concern me, but is there another way to *extend* configuration? As far as I'm concerned it's not a configurable module if config settings are blown away upon updating the module...

Comment: Could you explain how `$$phase`, in this context, is an anti-pattern? It seems pretty legitimate to me as `$apply` is already called on load, but is required when the window resizes to apply the updated font size. I've modified the code to remove this anti-pattern, but you essentially end up with something fairly messy in comparison: https://github.com/patrickmarabeas/ng-FitText.js/blob/master/ng-FitText.js#L55 I can understand in a lot of cases its usage means you are probably doing something wrong - but it seems like a more succinct readable solution here?

Comment: I understand that `$$phase` is Angular's internal method, and as such is not intended for regular use. Please see here for more specific details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346990/why-is-using-ifscope-phase-scope-apply-an-anti-pattern.

Comment: Concerning `debounce`, you could take it instead from the non-minimized version with comments, then another reader would better see what it does.

Comment: See also http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2605-scope-evalasync-vs-timeout-in-angularjs.htm about `$$phase`